# Filling up the empty blocks when the player touches the safe zone again! using cocos2d

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Hi guys i am stuck with filling up the data of all the blocks which are empty like the ones in the image.
[image] As you can see there i have a pacman like object where i will be moving around.

But when you are in the empty space where there are no Blue boxes available i should be able to add new blocks in the path of my pacman and when it touches  any other blue boxes like in the below case if my pacman touches the top row of the blue box i should be able to fill all the empty boxed inside the border of the path created by pacman.

For now i am using a 2d bool array to store all the filled boxed info like if there is a box inside i am making that cell in an array as true.

But how to fill the area with blue boxes after player finishes his path ?

Any help would be great thank you.

More info about this problem is here:
[filling the empty spaces in a certain region in a grid using c++](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80568/filling-the-empty-spaces-in-a-certain-region-in-a-grid-using-c)   [Same problem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80568/filling-the-empty-spaces-in-a-certain-region-in-a-grid-using-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use the [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm.  In your specific case you will probably want to fire off two different flood fills, one to the right of Pacman and one to the left.  Whichever one is suitable to fill (the smaller one, the one with no obstacles detected, etc.) is filled and the other is discarded.

Comment: Still Bit confused though because as you can see i want to fill only the spaces in the square region.

Comment: Yes thank you it solved my problem, i wish i can up vote you but i am allowed to with low rep i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple DFS algorithm !

**Here you go:**

1. Run DFS every time player go on a empty block.
2. Your DFS should navigate empty block until reach a filled (blue) block. this is stop
3. condition of your DFS.
4. Then in DFS, check if all DFS-branches stuck to a filled block. not your game-world border.
5. if yes, Run That DFS again, and fill all blocks which DFS navigate on. otherwise Nothing to do.