# filling the empty spaces in a certain region in a grid using c++

Tags: c++

[image]

[image]
Hi guys i am struggling to find the optimal way to fill the grid of a certain region.

In the above example lets say my player is at (7,5) and traveled (2,0) and i have the information of all the points he went through. 
for example: 
(7,5)->(6,5)->(4,5)->(4,4)->(4,3)->(3,3)->(2,3)....(2,0).

Here what i want to do is fill in either top side of the path with some color and bottom path with some other color.

and same goes for the other cases as well if player travels from (7,3)->(5,0) i want to color the insides with one color and out sides with another.

can any body explain me the logic to do this in c++ please thank you.

i went through that flood filling but not sure how to implement that for this one :( .

Comment: That image is really confusing. Couldn't you try to draw some simple step by step drawing, if possible also trying to fill things that should be considered solid or not to be painted or something like that?

Comment: Yes i added a new image which give a clear look my problem thank you.

Comment: So you essentially want to draw some path, then pick everything ontop (or on the left) and color it color 1, everything on the other side color 2?

Comment: ok i came that far but if you could tell me bit more elaborately that would be great i mean a logic in c++ to store all the up and bottom parts of the path.

Comment: That's no solution, I was just asking whether I understood the issue.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this if your tiles are objects is to set a bool for whether a tile has been visited, which you trigger when the player coords match a "visitable" tile's. Then at render time you can go through your tileList and make any bulk actions to all tiles which have been visited or not.

Comment: Well nicholas as i said above i am managing the you just highlighted but i was stuck at filling one side of the path with different color and other side with another .

right now i can think of doing it like record the path of the player if the player move from (5,3)->(4,3)->(4,2)->(3,2)->(3,1)->(3,0)
now that i have the info i want to fill the 3 column first untill  4 row from top 
next 2 column -> 1 -> 0 with respect to their x values.

Comment: Ok, then if all you need is to identify the columns and rows below/above the player's path, how about creating a new path with, for example, x coords = (playerPath.Tile1.x - 1), y coords = (playerPath.Tile1.y), and so on? If you got one path and need to know another one right next to it, you can just offset the coordinates by +- 1 on the x and y axis, then do with the new path as you wish.

Comment: Well my question was i have that grind info in an array so how do you loop through this data and fill in the relevant blocks with color :) thank you.

Comment: To loop through a 2D array, have you tried something like:  
  
    `for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)`  
 `for (int k = 0; k < height; ++k)`  
           `if tile[i][k]  //etc `

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I can't get the mini-Markdown to work. In case it isn't clear, it's two nested for loops that will allow you to go through your tile array accounting for every combination of `x` and `y` - then you can add whatever conditions you want to filter it down even more and reach the tiles you need.